# How to save a data set with a foreign key using combobox

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, combobox

I'm trying to save a data set in my table in mysql. Table *Sportart* is linked to table *Einheit*

*tbl_Sportart*
[Primary Key] **pk_sportart** [Text] **bezeichnung** [Foreign Key] **fk_einheit**

*tbl_Einheit*
[Primary Key] **pk_einheit** [Text] **bezeichnung**

Now I'm trying to save a Sportart using .jsp. The user can type in a **bezeichnung** and choose one **einheit** using a combobox. Unfortunately, I can't save the data set and I don't know if it's because of my combobox or my code for saving it (Apache Tomcat error: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.).

.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="save">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value='<c:out value="${sportart.id}"/>'/>
        <label for="inputVorname">Sportart</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSportart" placeholder="Sportart" name="sportart" required="required" value='<c:out value="${sportart.bezeichnung}"/>'>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">                
        <label for="inputName">Einheit</label>
        <p class="form-control-static">
        <select name="einheit">
            <c:forEach items="${einheit}" var ="einheit">
                <option value="${einheit.id}">${einheit.bezeichnung}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select> 
        </p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

SportartController.java

```
//Saves a sportart
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(Sportart sportart, Einheit einheit) {    
    sportart.setEinheit(einheit);
    Sportart result = sportartDao.save(sportart);

    if (sportart.getId() == null) {
        sportart.setId(result.getId());
    }
    return "redirect:findAll"; //Goes to findAll to show all Sportarts
}
```

SportartDao.java

```
public void create(String bezeichnung, Einheit einheit) {
    Sportart s = new Sportart(bezeichnung);
    s.setEinheit(einheit);
    save(s);
}
// Saves the {@link Sportart} in the database.
@Transactional
public Sportart save(Sportart sportart) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(sportart);
    return sportart;
}
```

Sportart.java

```
public class Sportart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "pk_sportart")
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_einheit", nullable = false)
    private Einheit einheit;
    private String bezeichnung;
    //getter and setter...
}
```